# How to place UI widgets on top of multiple Z ordered Surface Views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I have 2 `SurfaceViews` and 1 `button` and they need to be arranged in a way similar to the attached screenshot. I was able to get `SurfaceView B` to be on top of `SurfaceView A` by calling `surfaceViewB.setZOrderOnTop(true);`

The problem is that, once I do that, `SurfaceView B` is placed above the actual Window and I'm no longer able to get the Button to be on top of it (eg. calling `button.bringToFront()` is useless here).

Any idea how this layout could be accomplished?[image]

Comment: I'm not going to answer properly since I don't know the intricacies of  it, but basically SurfaceView is a weird View which is actually underneath all of your ui and the window cuts a hole through your ui so you can see it. Hopefully somebody more experienced can give you more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean)` to place SurfaceView B over SurfaceView A, but still behind the window. From documentation: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay%28boolean%29):

> public void setZOrderMediaOverlay (boolean isMediaOverlay)
>
> Control whether the surface view's surface is placed **on top of another
>   regular surface view in the window (but still behind the window
>   itself).** This is typically used to place overlays on top of an
>   underlying media surface view.
>
> Note that this must be set before the surface view's containing window
>   is attached to the window manager.
>
> Calling this overrides any previous call to setZOrderOnTop(boolean).

So, the following should work for you:

```
surfaceViewB.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i've already tried using this methods. I've actually tried every possible combination of setZOrderMediaOverlay on both SurfaceViews and no luck

Comment: My bad. Ultimately this WAS the right answer. I just wasn't able to see the final result at first since I had another view blocking my second surface view. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. My answer was based on Dianne Hackborn's reply here: [Link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/nDNQcceRnYA/ps9wTBfXIyEJ). I couldn't locate the thread at the time of posting or I would have included it in my answer.